# C# Static event null from within class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, events

I have created a static event inside of a class that I would like to subscribe to from other classes.

```
public class PlaylistModel 
{
    public static event EventHandler PlaylistLoadError;
    public static void LoadPlaylist() 
    {
        try 
        {    
           // ...do some stuff...
        } 
        catch(SomeException ex) 
        {
            EventHandler handler = PlaylistLoadError;

            if(handler != null) 
            {
                PlaylistLoadError(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my other class....

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage 
{
    public MainPage() 
    {
        PlaylistModel.PlaylistLoadError += PlaylistError;
    }

    public void PlaylistError(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    {
        //... show the error ...
    }
}
```

Inside of the catch, handler is null, despite it being subscribed to. I have debugged the program from within `MainPage` AFTER the catch has been executed, and `PlaylistLoadError` is shown as not being null. Any ideas why it would be null inside of `PlaylistModel`, but not anywhere else? I have a feeling it has something to do with it being static.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an `event` field can be null if nobody has subscribed to it. From your comments, it seems like the exception in your PlaylistModel class is thrown **before** the `MainPage` class is constructed at which point nobody has subscribed to the event yet.

Also please note that this is a recipe for memory leaks. When your `MainPage` class (or any other class) subscribes to the event, the `Playlist` class holds a reference to it and the event in the `Playlist` class is static. As such, all subscribed members to the event will live for the lifetime of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm positive it gets subscribed to because I watch it go by in the debugger. This even happens when the catch block is executed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the event delegate is copied when you assign it to a variable, but is likely null by the time you raise it:

```
EventHandler handler = PlaylistLoadError;

if(handler != null) { // not null
    PlaylistLoadError(null, null); // null
}
```

You can avoid the error by executing your local variable rather than re-obtaining the delegate from the event:

```
EventHandler handler = PlaylistLoadError;

if(handler != null) {
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

`this` and `EventArgs.Empty` are also better defaults than `null`

Comment: Unfortunately, PlaylistLoadError is in fact null. Any other ideas?

Comment: I set a breakpoint in MainPage and in LoadPlaylist to check the memory addresses of PlaylistLoadError. The static PlaylistLoadError referenced in MainPage is at one address, while the static PlaylistLoadError referenced in the (static) LoadPlaylist function is at another address. Why would this be?

Comment: @finkonkanonk - How is `PlaylistModel.LoadPlaylist` called?

Comment: It is called from other classes: `PlaylistModel plist = PlaylistModel.LoadPlaylist();`

Comment: @finkonkanonk - In that case, it's probably as simple as the Page_Load event on MainPage not having fired yet when LoadPlaylist is called.

Comment: That's the thing, it definitely has - I watch it go by in the debugger.