# Static functions have different static class variables?

Tags: c#, static, windows-phone

This is a followup to a previous question: [C# Static event null from within class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448910/c-sharp-static-event-null-from-within-class)

I have a class like this:

```
public class PlaylistModel {
    public static event EventHandler PlaylistLoadError;
    public static int myInt;

    public static void LoadPlaylist() 
    {
        try 
        {    
            // do some stuff, simulate exception
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        } 
        catch(InvalidOperationException ex) 
        {
           EventHandler handler = PlaylistLoadError;
           if(handler != null)  
           {
               PlaylistLoadError(null, null);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Else where in the program, I am setting the PlaylistLoadError EventHandler, like so:

```
public class MainPage {

    public MainPage() {
        PlaylistModel.PlaylistLoadError += MyErrorHandler;
        PlaylistModel.myInt = 5;
    }

    public static void MyErrorHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("There was an error");
    }
}
```

Now, inside of LoadPlaylist, PlaylistLoadError is null and myInt is 0, despite setting them elsewhere. Later, when I create an instance of PlaylistModel, PlaylistLoadError and myInt are the correct values. So my question is this - do static functions of a class somehow access different versions of static class variables? I have checked the memory addresses of the static variables, and they are indeed different depending on if I'm inside of a non-static vs. a static function.

Comment: No.  Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: ? This is code that reproduces the problem...

Comment: No, I cannot run this and repro the problem.  You need this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I did the same. no problem. everything was OK!

Comment: Which one is run first?  Are you calling LoadPlaylst before setting the handler and the int?  Be sure.  Put breakpoints on the applicable lines.

Comment: Ok, I just tried running this in its own project, and it seemed to work fine -_- LoadPlaylist is called when the user clicks a button - could that be the issue? And if so, is there a good way to remedy it?

Comment: You said it works fine, and then ask if there is a way to remedy it without stating a problem.

Comment: I ran it in its own console project, and it worked fine. When I run it in my Windows Phone project, it doesn't. The only difference between the two is that LoadPlaylist is called inside of a button click event handler in my Windows Phone project.

Comment: How are you storing you playlist?  Are you sure that that storage method is compatible with windows phone? Does it work with the desktop emulator?  Did you try setting a break-point (as detailed below) while running it in the emulator?  If it's not working on windows-phone it is probably an issue with how the windows-phone api is interpreting you code. You should mention that you are running this on windows-phone in your question.  Also I added a tag for windows-phone so others could find it.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are static and will remain the same while the program is running unless something is called to change it.

If you want to find out what is happening I would change the field to:

```
private static int _myInt;
```

and then add:

```
public static int myInt
{ 
    get { return _myInt; } 
    set { _myInt = value; }
}
```

and then add a break point at on `set` so you can find out when it is being changed.